# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in AIDL Service

Tags: android, service, aidl

I have a problem with a set of AIDL services.

I have an Android application that contains the AIDL files in a packet called
es.mypackage.services. These AIDL files are well defined and they have the correct names.
In addition, this package contains the implementations of these AIDL file.
These java implementations are defined in the manifest as services.
After compiling, a package es.mypackage.services is created in the gen folder.

Apart from this android application I have another app that it's just a client of these services. In this app, I have a package also called es.mypackage.services that contains the same AIDL files. After compiling, a package es.mypackage.services is created in the gen folder.

Then, I run the "server" application in a device. Then, I also run the "client" in the same device obtaining the following error in LogCat:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: es.mypackage.services.MyService
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3499):at es.mypackage.services.MyService.onBind(MyService.java:26)
```

Well, the code of this line nº26 is "return new IMyService.Stub()" that is inside:

```
  @Override  
  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
  { return new IMyService.Stub()    
    { ….
```

I don't know what is happening. Had somebody the same problem? Thanks in advance.